# Images counter on a page

Tags: php

I am trying to get the number of images that are present in the current page. I just found a JS method but i would like to find a method via php. How can i get the same result of this script by PHP?

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.images.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: Get the data and send it to php via form submit or ajax.

Comment: PHP does not run in the browser. You must send it via a request to a PHP script.

Comment: Why would you want to do this with PHP instead of JS?

Comment: I have two kind of pages, in the first one there are images, in the second one there are video. I want detect in which pages there are images. Am i using the wrong method?

Comment: get the contents of the page (curl, file_get_contents) and count img tags (wither with DomDocument, some crawler library like symfony crawler, or even counting occurences of `<img` might be enough depending on your case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?PHP
$code= file_get_contents($url); //this line is getting HTML code from the website
echo substr_count($code, '<img');
?>
```

Comment: I receive a "file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty" error. Should i replace `$url` with something?

Comment: Yes, you should. Via `file_get_contents` you can get the HTML code from the URL. If you have the HTML code `file_get_contents` doesn't need.